# Nested svn repositories

Tags: svn

I got a "Project A" in repository. But in that project I'm using a library, which is hosted on Google Code. There is my question: is there any way, to have that library files "hooked" to Google Code SVN, and simultaneously my project in my repo (it's parent to that library), so I can commit library files into my repository when I decide, that outer project revision is ok?

I've tried to do checkout in the library folder, files were downloaded from Google's Code repository. But I that case wasn't able to add them to my repository - they weren't visible in "Add" window.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use an [External](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html) which will causes SVN to checkout the latest version of the external files, when you checkout your repository.

From the above page:

> The convenience of the svn:externals property is that once it is set on a versioned directory, everyone who checks out a working copy with that directory also gets the benefit of the externals definition. In other words, once one person has made the effort to define those nested working copy checkouts, no one else has to bother—Subversion will, upon checkout of the original working copy, also checkout the external working copies.