# tortoise svn update also auto updates all nested svns

Tags: svn, nested, updates

I use TortoiseSVN 1.9.5 and have a svn repo (main) and within that a different snv repo (sub). Whenever I want to update I need to call update on the main, than navigate to sub and call update on sub.

Is there a way to make this nested update work via right click on main in file explorer and this triggers update for all nested repos?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer is already here :) - in case anyone else find this one first

[Nested svn repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405535/nested-svn-repositories)